# override main class static function in php

Tags: php, class, oop, overriding

I have a class as below:

```
class Base {

  public static function test() {
     echo "A";
  }
}
```

Now i want to create new class with extending it with Base class so that i can override base class function

```
 class Basenew extends Base{
   function test(){
     echo "B";
   }
 }
```

It must work as below:

when i use below code:

```
Base::test();
```

It must output `B` rather than outputting `A`

How can i do this in php. Please help.

Comment: Only with a black magic.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's `extends`, not `extend`.

Secondly you cant make a static method non static while you are trying to override it.

Thirdly if you are overriding then use the child class to see the changes, not the base class.

```
<?php

class Base {

  public static function test() {
     echo "A";
  }
}

 class Basenew extends Base{
   static function test(){
     echo "B";
   }
 }

 Basenew::test();      //B
 Base::test();         //This will still say A because its still the parent class.

 ?>
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/200593)**

Comment: Oh it was typo mistake. yes i know that it works what you have answered. but i want to know if it is possible to achieve the workflow i mentioned in my question. Means if i use base class and call function it call child class function?

Comment: Nope that's not possible. A parent doesn't ordinarily know who the child class is and who extended it.

Comment: Thanks Hanky.. is there any other solution? in php?

Comment: That's a little too broad, there could be some ways of doing that but then one wonders what's the rationale behind that? If the child class has nothing to do in the equation then why not simply update the base class method to do what you want it to do? The way you're trying is not really OOP at all :)